# How to change a value in json file within a loop?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using a JSON file to store the number of warnings a user has. When a user is warned, I want to increase the number of warnings.

This is the JSON sample I use :

```
{
"users": {
    "976797937789198397" : "1",
    "270904126974590976" : "2",
    "871490226692976791" : "1"

}  }
```

This is the code I use to fetch the number of warnings a user has, and this works without any errors. I just need a way to find out how to add +1 to a user every time they are warned.

```
@commands.command()
async def getWarns(self, ctx : commands.Context, member : discord.Member):
    with open('warns.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        await ctx.send(data["users"][f"{member.id}"])
```

Comment: You just retrieve a value of the outer dictionary which is also a dictionary. Then you get, modify and set a value of the inner dictionary. What is the problem?

Comment: What have you tried? It's impossible to know what *specific* problem you are facing without this, and the question ends up being a code-writing request which is off-topic for SO. Please see [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use int() to convert the value of the specific ID to int, then increase it by 1.
Something like:

```
f = {
"users": {
    "976797937789198397" : "1",
    "270904126974590976" : "2",
    "871490226692976791" : "1"

}  }

warn_int = int(f['users']['976797937789198397'])

if userIsWarned:
    warn_int = warn_int +1
    f['users']['976797937789198397'] = str(warn_int)
```

Comment: If the value will always be used as integers, then it should be stored as integers instead of strings. Will make these operations much easier.

Comment: @Benjin I agree, but in his examples, he had strings, that is why I gave my answer like that

Comment: @bogdaN, I've faced many situations where I'm working with existing data that required conversions like this. It's a useful answer. But if the OP is in a position to change how the data is stored, I agree that it would be better to store it as a number. Unfortunately that's not always an option.

Comment: I tried this code, but on the last line `f["users"]['976797937789198397'] = str(warn_int)`, it doesn't do anything in the JSON file. Please note I had opened my file with 'r+' mode.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Not really, it didn't show any errors, nor did it do anything to the JSON file.